# How to run a single scenario in Karate?

Tags: karate

To test a specific feature in karate I run:

`mvn test -Dkarate.options="classpath:myfeature.feature"`

Is there a way to run a single scenario defined into a feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can via tags: https://github.com/intuit/karate#tags

Also note that you can run a scenario by name, for e.g. if the name is "first":

```
mvn test -Dkarate.options="classpath:myfeature.feature --name ^first$"
```

And if you use IntelliJ - you can right click and do the above.

EDIT: Karate now supports being able to use a line-number, for e.g. `some.feature:42` so it will invoke only the `Scenario` or outline `Example` on line 42 - this is designed only for IDE-s and developer mode, use a tag for maintainability.

Comment: Thanks @peter-thomas for the hints. I tryed the `--name` option, but did't works: all scenarios are always executed regardless the exp i set for the name.
Do you have any advice?

Comment: @LorenzoNardi no other than just use a tag. this is what most teams do. put a tag called `@debug` for example, and you can leave it in without any issues, and simpler to use / type

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing something, but in order to use tags (more information here https://github.com/intuit/karate#tags), I had to run the following command:

```
mvn clean test -Dkarate.options="--tags @name=value"
```

Leaving it here for anyone who also can't run it via the other answer.