# How to specify a single scenario with jar file?

Tags: karate

I am trying to follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54766711/11236740) to run a specific scenario and I am failing at doing this when running the stand-alone version (v0.9.1).

My experiments:

(1) 
`java -Dkarate.options="--name ^bla$" -jar karate.jar features/many.feature`

It runs all scenarios from the feature file.

(2) 
`java -Dkarate.options="classpath:features/many.feature --name ^bla$" -jar karate.jar`

starts the UI without executing a test case.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `tags` will be a convenient way for this

add a different tag before each scenario and pass the tag name with `-t` while calling with karate standalone

*many.feature*

```
Feature: Many scenario
 @s1
 Scenario: SOne
   * print 'first scenario'
 @s2
 Scenario: Stwo
   * print 'second scenario'
```

Now pass the scenario tag like,

```
java -jar karate.jar many.feature -t @s1
```

Comment: I really would like to avoid creating a single tag per test case. Tags are a means for *grouping* and by creating a tag per scenario, I do not achieve grouping.

So would it be possible the call a test case by name as implied by the post I linked in my original post?

Comment: @chbndrhnns update - this has been fixed in this ticket: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/773 and in fact you can now run a scenario by line-number: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/770